# MongoError: exception: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a query is run I have this result for System.js

```
db.collection.find({}).count();
result : 187467
```

when I recovered essye of the result with one using toArray

```
db.collection.find({'date':{$gt:ISODate('2015-06-07') }}).toArray(function(err, results){
return results
});
```

I got an error message

> MongoError: exception: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728
>   bytes, past the 64MB limit?

I think I have a problem of memory but I not find how configure the memory in the server mongodb.
Is there a solution to reconfigure memory?